# Plasma desktop doesn't start automatically after apt-get upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, taskbar

After applying updates, my desktop doesn't launch anymore at boot.

Instead of plasma, I have a bash prompt. I have to log in and run `startx` to get plasma running. 
However, when it is launched, I don't have any taskbar and don't have any possible right click on the desktop.

I tried several `apt-get upgrade` but the problem is still there.

Kernel version

```
$ uname -a
Linux PouetPouetStation 4.7.0-040700rc7-generic #201607110032 SMP Mon Jul 11 04:34:25 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Plasma-desktop version

```
$ apt list plasma-desktop -a
Listing... Done
plasma-desktop/xenial,now 4:5.8.6-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
plasma-desktop/xenial 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1 amd64
```

Can anybody help to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.
Steven

---

**Update:**

After following the advice of installing `sddm`, I could login to the desktop. But now I don't have any panel or start menu and I can't right click on the desktop to add a panel.

Comment: Check if sddm is installed there. If not install it using `sudo apt install sddm` and restart

Comment: Well spotted ! It was not installed ! Thanks ! Any idea about the missing task bar ?

Comment: Can you login to the desktop now?

Comment: Yes, but I have to use  `[ALT]+[F2]` to run any application because I don't have any "Start menu"

Comment: Can you right click on the desktop? If yes, right click on the desktop and select "Add panel" -> "Default panel"

Comment: Actually I can't, there is no working right click on the desktop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58752/discussion-between-anwar-and-steven).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you were missing the display manager `sddm`. Install it with the command and restart

```
sudo apt install sddm
```

Now, Once logged in OP was unable to find the default panel. Right clicking on the desktop doesn't work. We discussed the problem in chat and it seems the right click action for desktop was misconfigured.

So, OP needed to click on the top-left corner icon and select *Configure desktop*, and from there go to the *Mouse action* tab and configure the right click action so that it yields the *Standard Menu*.

Once done and applied, right clicking on the desktop and selecting *Add panel* -> *Default panel* should make the panel with all the standard widget to appear.